# Are well-defined theoretical or custom Magic questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Let's say I'm working on custom cards for fun, within Magic's rules. If I had a new mechanic, would it be on-topic to ask a question about the rules implication of the mechanic?

For example, if I had a mechanic which was intended to make a creature's power always match its toughness after modifications. If I posted my initial definition:  means that this creature's power is equal to its toughness. I'd receive an answer explaining how layers would make this wording not work, and how the ability could be worded within the rules.

By "well-defined", I mean that the question is **not** about how to balance the effect, nor seeking opinionated feedback.

This question refers to Magic, but could apply to any rules system.

Would questions like this be on-topic, as they help people explore and understand the rules, or off-topic because they don't answer questions about the existing game, and wouldn't be practically useful to the vast majority of readers?

Comment: Khans of Tarkir green Enchantment, Assault Formation.

Answer (score 12):

I am generally in favor of questions about custom Magic cards. They're interesting ways of exploring nuances in the rules, and that's valuable especially with rules as complex as Magic's.

I think that if we do choose to allow this, we have to accept that most questions will be of the form "Does this custom card function as I intend it to?" or "What does this custom ability do?", and that in some cases, the only correct answer will be "This is not covered by the rules". We should also encourage people to not only answer whether the card works but also to describe how it functions in edge cases, and especially cover interactions that break the game.

Comment: I like this - having some guidance on how to answer in a more useful and informative way helps provide questions of the type "does this work?" with answers that explore the rules more deeply, rather than just "no - because of rule XXX". This makes the answers more useful to people beyond just the card creator.