# How should we be tagging questions about custom Magic cards?

Tags: discussion, tags, magic-the-gathering

We recently reached agreement that questions about custom cards were OK: [Are well-defined theoretical or custom Magic questions on-topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/are-well-defined-theoretical-or-custom-magic-questions-on-topic)

And we've received a few questions on the topic:

- [How could you change what creature a creature with soulbond is paired with?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34068/how-could-you-change-what-creature-a-creature-with-soulbond-is-paired-with)
- [How concise can I get the Soulbond boilerplate in a homebrew card without functional changes?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-concise-can-i-get-the-soulbond-boilerplate-in-a-homebrew-card-without-functi)
- [Can I make a card that places a +1/+1 counter on an enchantment that isn't a creature?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34171/can-i-make-a-card-that-places-a-1-1-counter-on-an-enchantment-that-isnt-a-cre)

So far I've been tagging these questions with [custom-game-pieces](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-game-pieces) but that feels like kind of a janky name to apply, considering it's largely been about physical crafts, and considering we're largely also talking about [game-design](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design) (which also seems appropriate but which I haven't been using yet).

What tags should I be using for a question about creating custom cards for [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We already have a number of tags about some aspect of *Magic: The Gathering* such as [mtg-online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online), [mtg-cube](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-cube), [mtg-drafting](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-drafting), [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander) (most of these are related to Magic formats).

Given that, I'd like to recommend we tag such questions as [mtg-homebrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-homebrew) or [mtg-custom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-custom). Another option would be [mtg-homebrew-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-homebrew-cards) or [mtg-custom-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-custom-cards), but I think that a broader tag would be good in case we get questions about homebrew rules and such not specifically related to homebrew cards.

My personal preference is [mtg-homebrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-homebrew) as that is an unambiguous term, but I'd be okay with [mtg-custom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-custom) if that seems too niche.

Comment: [tag:mtg-custom]? Shorter and makes more sense to people who aren't acquainted with the term *homebrew* as applies to gaming.

Comment: @Nij "Custom" doesn't mean much specifically though, leaving [mtg-custom] an ambiguous and weirdly phrased tag. As an adjective, custom *what* -- custom decks maybe (as opposed to premade ones)? Or is it "custom" as a noun, as in "etiquette"?

Comment: I would have to agree with @doppelgreener said. With the game as it stands there are way to many different aspects of it that could be considered custom. Even at the basics custom could refer to all the different counters, pay mats or storage solutions that could be used.

Comment: Since it's been about a week with no other answers, and this solution seems pretty functional and has decent support (+6/-0), I've added the [tag:mtg-homebrew] tag to these questions.

Comment: mtg-homebrew is simply inaccurate - mtg-custom-cards is far superior =p

Comment: @corsiKa Would you like to leave an answer advocating for that tag?